# bazel golang build fails when project has internal dependency

Tags: go, build, bazel

I'm on MacOS 10.13.2.
Go 1.10.
bazel 0.11.1

I need to compile a repo that has 2 projects (project1 and project2).
project1 has 2 subpacakges. p1lib and dep1
p1lib uses dep1.

I generate BUILD files with gazelle, files look ok.

```
gazelle -go_prefix=github.com/BazelBuildForGo
```

But when I run build I get an error that says that I'm missing direct dependency.

```
bazel build //project1
INFO: Analysed target //project1:project1 (3 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user1/df78026a5ee0c7ed3d23dd05c3a3b1f7/external/com_github_wix_private_bazelbuildforgo/project1/p1lib/BUILD.bazel:3:1: GoCompile external/com_github_wix_private_bazelbuildforgo/project1/p1lib/darwin_amd64_stripped/go_default_library~/github.com/BazelBuildForGo/project1/p1lib.a failed (Exit 1)
2018/03/25 18:02:55 missing strict dependencies:
    external/com_github_wix_private_bazelbuildforgo/project1/p1lib/p1lib.go: import of github.com/wix-private/BazelBuildForGo/project1/dep1, which is not a direct dependency
Target //project1:project1 failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.358s, Critical Path: 0.12s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

My project can be found here 
https://github.com/wix-playground/BazelBuildForGo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the import prefix you passed to Gazelle on the command line (`github.com/BazelBuildForGo`) is different from the imports in the .go files (`github.com/wix-private/BazelBuildForGo`). When Gazelle sees imports that are outside the current prefix, it will generate external dependencies for those imports, and those dependencies will be missing:

```
go_library(
    name = "go_default_library",
    srcs = ["p1lib.go"],
    importpath = "github.com/BazelBuildForGo/project1/p1lib",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = ["@com_github_wix_private_bazelbuildforgo//project1/dep1:go_default_library"],
)
```

The fix for this is pretty easy though. Just run Gazelle with the prefix `github.com/wix-private/BazelBuildForGo`. You actually already have this in `//:gazelle`, so just run that, then rebuild.

```
$ bazel run //:gazelle
$ bazel build //...
```

That will change the `go_library` rule above to this:

```
go_library(
    name = "go_default_library",
    srcs = ["p1lib.go"],
    importpath = "github.com/wix-private/BazelBuildForGo/project1/p1lib",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = ["//project1/dep1:go_default_library"],
)
```